# Space after Polish character when displaying content property in ":after" pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using successfully Polish characters in whole project. But i added global loader whenever axios action is performing. And I have such CSS code for this loader:

```
.loader:after {
  content: "Ładowanie...";
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.5rem;        
}

.loader:before {
  content: '';
  background: #000000cc;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

And the problem is: it doesn't display "Ładowanie..." but "Ł  adowanie..." - with space after Polish character.

Also I'm using react-bootstrap in my project. I'm telling you this although it might be unnecessary info, but I have no idea what may cause this, so better to tell more than less.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljEyx.png)

[Screenshot with different Polish character (everything fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9fB6.png)

Comment: Displays fine on Chrome 71 https://jsfiddle.net/Lxjsmkyv/

Comment: Your problem is not in that CSS (I just made a snippet of it and it's working fine). You should look in other parts of your code and maybe share them.

Comment: hmm, ok. thx for info, I will dig deeper

Comment: when I'm displaying "Ladowanie" instead of "Ładowanie" it's perfectly fine :/

Comment: Maybe the `.loader` styling ? Maybe the custom font you use doesn't display your "Ł" correctly ?

Comment: I've tried to write this character with Unicode and nothing, I've tried different polish characters and then everything was fine (I've added screenshots to my question). Also I added :before of .loading. But which part of this class would cause such bug?